# Set HTTP Header Cookie with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, header

I am trying to set some header cookies in node.js by using the following method

```
 response.setHeader("Set-Cookie", "username=" + data.name);
```

the data variable is a json object which contains a number of fields/values, received through a previously sent ajax request. The **data.name** field is definitely populated (a previous console.log(data.name) shows the value correctly).

However, in the browser, once this header has been sent with response.end(), it shows up the following way (in Chrome, while inspecting the response headers in the network tab)

```
 Set-Cookie:username=undefined
```

Does anyone have an idea how to do this properly?

What I want to accomplish is identifying users throughout a session **WITHOUT** using any third-party bloat like express.js. I have already tried using session.js with no success.

Thankful for any ideas.

Comment: `usermail` !== `username`. Is that a typo here only or could that be the cause of your problem?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It is a typo here only.

Comment: Does the value show if you put a console.log(data.name) directly before setHeader?

Comment: @caeth - yes, it does, i just double checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I know that you said that you are sure that `data.name` is defined, your code appears to be so simple, that I am questioning whether it is actually defined.

Rather than logging to console, try setting the the header cookie with some explicit checking:

```
response.setHeader(
    "username=" +
    (
        data ?
            data.hasOwnProperty( "name" ) ?
                data.name ?
                    data.name : "name empty"
                : "name undefined"
            : "data undefined"
    )
);
```

This won't solve your problem, but will help you understand what part of `data.name` is not working as intended.

Comment: Thanks, this has led me to the solution. I feel kind of dumb - I had two nested callbacks which both used a variable named "data", so evidently I was trying to read the "name" field from the "data" object, which was overwritten by the 2nd "data" object in the inner function.